# How do I find a face with too many edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I’ve downloaded a free obj from internet.

And there seems to be a face with 7 edges hidden somewhere in which I cannot find manually.

I need to keep it down below 4.

How do I find faces with too many edges, and how do I eliminate it?

Comment: Hi :). *Select > Select All By trait > Faces by sides*. Then you can specify to only select faces with 7 sides :)

Comment: In Edit mode, Select > Select all by Trait > Faces by Sides and on the lower left settings dialog that appears increase the Number of Vertices to 7. It's probably best to be in wireframe mode (ALT-Z) for this in case it's an internal face. You'll then have to decide the best method to remove the face (dissolve, delete, merge vertices, etc.).

Comment: You can also select 'More Than' or 'Less Than' your given parameter.. eg 'More Than' 4.